# Adding a "Facebook Pixel" to a Mac App using JS

Tags: javascript, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to measure conversion of ads to install a Mac App.

FB provides javascript code that should be embedded in a website.
However, I need to use run code from Objective-C.

Here are the installation instructions from FB for using in a website:
[image]
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/218844828315224

Assuming that there is no lower-level API (e.g. use a plain GET/POST request) I believe that the only option is to call JS from Objective-C.

So far I was able to create a class with a JSContext (available as part of the JavaScriptCore framework) like the snippets below, but FB says that the pixel has "No Activity Yet".

What's the correct way to use Facebook Pixel within Objective-C?

```
JSContext* context = [[JSContext alloc] init];

NSString* jsCode = ... // The JS code from the instructions above.
JSValue * v1 = [context evaluateScript:jsCode];

static const char* loadPixel =
  "var downloadingImage = new Image();"
  "downloadingImage.src = \"https://www.facebook.com/tr? id=0123456789&ev=PageView&noscript=1\"";

JSValue * v2 = [context evaluateScript:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:loadPixel]];
```